# Smarty() vs SmatyC()

Tags: php, smarty2

I`ve found old webpage writen with Smarty2 and I don't understand this. Could you tell me the difference between:

```
$_Html = new SmartyC(TRUE);
and
$_Html = new Smarty();
```

I can't find SmartyC() in manual.

Comment: Maybe SmartyC is a custom class that extends the original Smarty class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the whole website project for `class SmartyC`. I assume, you will find a custom class, which extends the original Smarty class in some way like:

```
class SmartyC extends Smarty
{
  function _construct($b)
  {
    // do something with $b like
    // if($b)
    // {
    //    $this->caching = true;
    // }
  }
}
```

Comment: It`s constructor from smarty compiler